# Windows 10 UWP - White space on Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'am developing a Windows 10 Universal App and every time I debug it on the Windows Phone emulator, I get the following "white space" on the top of my view (yellow in the picture).

Does somebody know this issue? What can I do?

When I debug it on my local machine (as a windows store app) there is no white space on top. Maybe it is the navigation bar or something like that??? It seems like there is a top margin set to all of my views ...

[image: White space on the top of the view - example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Status Bar, which only shows up on mobile. In UWP, the background color of the Status Bar seems to inherit from the background of the main page. So, if the background color of your Page is set to White, but your RequestedTheme is set to Dark, you'd see something like this. Try changing the background color of your main page, or the RequestedTheme property.

It's also possible to hide the Status Bar in a UWP app.

I wrote up a quick blog post about this:
https://stenobot.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/uwp-app-development-styling-the-mobile-status-bar/

Comment: Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();  worked for this in Windows 8.1 think it's still same in Windows 10, although there was a bug in old Windows 10 Mobile build where it wouldn't hide I think

Comment: I was able to hide the Status Bar using the above method, but I had to add a reference to the following SDK in the project file:

<ItemGroup>
    <SDKReference Include="Windows Mobile, Version=10.0.0.1"/>
</ItemGroup>

Comment: Thank you stenobot! Thats the solution! :)